# Scroll UITableView using second UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have an application, that uses external display.

I have real table view on my iPad, and mirror table view on external screen.

Now, I'm using `NSNotification` center to notify table on external view that it must scroll, but scrolling is very rough, visually not sexy with lags.

**How can i improve the performance of this? How to make it smooth and sexy?**

Yes, both TableViews have different sizes.

Here is my code:

Controller with real `UITableView`:

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
   {
       if (scrollView == self.iboTable)
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]    postNotificationName:@"remoteControlTableScrolled" object:scrollView];
    }
```

And the controller that is on external screen:

```
- (void)TableScrolled:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    UITableView *notificationTableView = notification.object;
    if(notificationTableView.contentOffset.y>self.iboTable.contentSize.height - self.iboTable.bounds.size.height) 
    {
        CGFloat yOffset = 0;
        yOffset = self.iboTable.contentSize.height - self.iboTable.bounds.size.height;

        [self.iboTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, yOffset) animated:YES];
    }
    else if(notificationTableView.contentOffset.y + notificationTableView.frame.size.height == notificationTableView.contentSize.height)
    {
        [self.iboTable scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, self.iboTable.contentSize.height - self.iboTable.bounds.size.height, self.iboTable.bounds.size.width, self.iboTable.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.iboTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(notificationTableView.contentOffset.x,notificationTableView.contentOffset.y)animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with blocks instead of NSNotificationCenter

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean with blocks

Comment: I hope @jailani is suggesting to use delegates or blocks to notify instead of NSNotification

Comment: There 4 ways of communication are available in ios 1.Delegates 2.Call Backs 3.NSNotification 4.KVO & KVC.

Comment: Blocks are like function pointer in c: You can declare NSBlock VC2(Controller from real table view) and define it VC1(External view controller). Assign your block from VC1 and call it from VC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem, in this line:

```
 [self.iboTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(notificationTableView.contentOffset.x,notificationTableView.contentOffset.y)animated:YES];
```

animated: NO;

animation leads to lags and not smooth scrolling, because it is used to animated scroll ONCE, for example till the 10th element!

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are a clumsy mechanism for posting so many of them at such short periods.

Have a reference of your external screen view controller in your main screen view controller, and in `scrollViewDidScroll:` set the content offset accordingly.

Comment: tried this, works better but still not sexy. And i used my code for offsetting, because the sizes are different, maybe my code is not good?